# X rotation doesn't work

Tags: python, 3d, rotation, rendering

In python, I have written a 3D rendering program. The Y rotation works fine, but the X rotation zooms in for some obscure reason. I couldn't spot it, so I put it up here.

```
def plotLine(W, H, (x, y, z), (x2, y2, z2), rotX, rotY, FOV=1.0):
    try:
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        z = float(z)
        x2 = float(x2)
        y2 = float(y2)
        z2 = float(z2)
        if z == 0:
            z = 0.01
        if z2 == 0:
            z2 = 0.01
        x, y, z = rotateY((x, y, z), rotY)
        x, y, z = rotateX((x, y, z), rotX)
        x2, y2, z2 = rotateY((x2, y2, z2), rotY)
        x2, y2, z2 = rotateX((x2, y2, z2), rotX)
        scX = (x/z)*FOV
        scY = (y/z)*FOV
        scX *= min(W, H)
        scY *= min(W, H)
        scX += W/2
        scY += H/2
        scX2 = (x2/z2)*FOV
        scY2 = (y2/z2)*FOV
        scX2 *= min(W, H)
        scY2 *= min(W, H)
        scX2 += W/2
        scY2 += H/2
        pygame.draw.aaline(display, (0, 255, 0), (scX, scY), (scX2, scY2))
    except (OverflowError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return


def rotateY((x, y, z), degrees): # Looking left and right.
    x, y, z = float(x), float(y), float(z)
    rads = math.radians(degrees)
    newX = (math.cos(rads)*x)+(math.sin(rads)*z)
    newY = y
    newZ = (-math.sin(rads)*x)+(math.cos(rads)*z)

    return (newX, newY, newZ)

def rotateX((x, y, z), degrees):
    x, y, z = float(x), float(y), float(z)
    rads = math.radians(degrees)
    newX = x
    newY = (math.cos(rads)*y)+(math.sin(rads)*z)
    newZ = (math.sin(rads)*y)+(math.cos(rads)*z)

    return (newX, newY, newZ)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

BTW, I have looked up the matrix rotations on Wikipedia. Either Wikipedia got the matrices wrong, or I multiplied the matrices wrong, which is not likely. I have looked over them several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an error in your rotateX function

```
newY = (math.cos(rads)*y)+(math.sin(rads)*z)
newZ = (math.sin(rads)*y)+(math.cos(rads)*z)
```

should be

```
newY = (math.cos(rads)*y)+(math.sin(rads)*z)
newZ = (-math.sin(rads)*y)+(math.cos(rads)*z)
        ^
        ^
```

without the negative sign you will not get a rotation. You have done this correctly in your `rotateY` function but not the `rotateX` function.

If you look at the 2D submatrix of your currently coded 3D rotation you have

```
[cos(rads)  sin(rads)]
[sin(rads)  cos(rads)]
```

and the determinant of this is

```
1/(cos(rads)*cos(rads) - sin(rads)sin(rads)) 
= 1/cos(2*rads)
```

This is not equal to 1 for all angles `rads` and hence is not a rotation for all values of `rads`.

Note also that this rotation angle would be in the negative sense to what is usually associated with a rotation. You can see more information about this [here on wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Non-standard_orientation_of_the_coordinate_system)

Comment: I don't know how I didn't spot that! Thanks for responding so quickly. Now it works xD!

Comment: Missing/incorrect signs are usually at the root of lots of mathematical problems!! We all do it!!